# We had a lot of difficulty in finding or to find the house

Tags: sentence-choice

Which one to choose and is there any rule which I can go through:

> 1. We had a lot of difficulty **in finding** the house.
> 2. We had a lot of difficulty **to find** the house.

Suggestions please.

Answer (score 4):

Use ***difficulty in***.

There are several ways to think of this (i.e., why you should use *difficulty in* rather than *difficulty to*, e.g. collocation, licensing, etc.), but I usually think of this as "pattern". You can find most of the common patterns of common verbs and nouns in most dictionaries. For example, here is a note in [Longman English Dictionary Online](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/difficulty):

> ​! Do not say that someone 'has difficulty to do something'. Say that someone **has difficulty doing something** or **has difficulty in doing something**.